# How does the state of iodine affect its HOMO–LUMO gap?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, phase

My teacher told me that the HOMO–LUMO gap in solid iodine is smaller than that in gaseous iodine.

When I asked about the reason, he told me that it is due to higher interactions in solid iodine as compared to gaseous iodine, which I did not understand. How can the physical state of a compound affect the HOMO–LUMO gap, even though the chemical formula is the same?

Comment: Chemical formula of solid Na and gaseous Na is also the same: Na. But I suppose you aren't surprised that their HOMO/LUMO stuff is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will broadly mention several mechanisms that may influence color of a solid vs. gas, not just the HOMO-LUMO transition.
Without going into the literature and/or performing (extensive) calculations, I cannot confirm or reject your teacher explanation.

- In the solid state, you may find intermolecular MO interactions that will affect orbital energies. Depending on the strength, you may even have to abandon the concept of *molecular* orbitals in favor of *crystal* orbitals. [Quantum dots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot) and their dependence of color on size are somewhat of an example.
- Molecules may alter their shape in solid state compared to gaseous state. This is less of an issue in $\ce{I2}$.
- In the solid state, intermolecular excitations are more likely (*i.e.* going beyond HOMO-LUMO transitions). This is especially true if you do not have a pure substance, think doped solids.
- Note that supermicroscopic spatial distribution of a substance will have influence on the color as well: finely distributed silver or mercury (as in calomel) may appear as black rather than shiny.

Comment: What are quantum dots ?